# Tunneling two different instances of LAN Syncthing via SSH

Tags: ssh, tunnel, syncthing

I have the following configuration:
Two Syncthing instances running on PC1 and PC2(home) respectively on LAN1 and LAN2(home). Following [this](https://docs.syncthing.net/users/tunneling.html) guide i set "Sync Protocol Listen Addresses" value to tcp://127.0.0.1:22000 and Remote device "Addresses" value to tcp://127.0.0.1:22001. Therefore, each Syncthing instance will have three open ports: 22000 and 22001 for connection and data transfer, and 8384 for the WebGUI. To enable remote access, I have set up port forwarding on my router, redirecting public port 3333 to port 4444 on PC2, where an sshd server is listening.

Now, my question is: How can I tunnel the three ports (22000, 22001 and 8384) using SSH, so that I can securely transfer files with Syncthing and control the PC2 Syncthing instance from my PC1 browser? I want to achieve this using the native Windows SSH client and have the command window automatically close after executing the command.

Note: Currently, I am using PuTTY to accomplish this by following these steps:

```
In PuTTY, I enter "MY_ROUTERS_PUBLIC_IP" in the "Host Name" field under "Session."
I set the "Port" to 3333.
Under "Connection" -> "SSH" -> "Auth," I specify "MY_PRIVATE_KEY_FOR_PC2" as the authentication method.
Under "Connection" -> "SSH" -> "Tunnels," I configure the following: L22001 127.0.0.1:22000 and R22001 127.0.0.1:22000.
```

However, there are a few issues with this setup:

1. The PuTTY window remains open at all times.
2. Furthermore, due to my reliance on internet-sourced commands without a complete understanding of their functionality, I ended up tunneling only ports 22000 and 22001. Consequently, the GUI for Syncthing PC2 is not being forwarded to my PC1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve the same as above using the command line:

```
ssh -L22001:127.0.0.1:22000 -R22001:127.0.0.1:22000 -N -f -p 3333 USERNAME@MY_ROUTERS_PUBLIC_IP
```

- `-L22001:127.0.0.1:22000` connects port 22001 on PC1 to 22000 on PC2 (tunnel).
- `-R22001:127.0.0.1:22000` connects port 22001 on PC2 to 22000 on PC1 (reverse tunnel).
- `-N` means do not start a command line session on the remote machine; we're only using the tunnels.
- `-f` means that the process continues to run if you close the terminal window (Windows works a little differently from other OS here). You often see these last two together as `-fN`, but I separated them for clarity.
- `-p 3333` sets the port number to use with MY_ROUTERS_PUBLIC_ADDRESS.

To add the Syncthing control port, create a tunnel from PC1 to PC2:8384 like this:

`-L8385:127.0.0.1:8384`

I chose 8385 arbitrarily as the local port. You can connect from the browser using `http://12.0.0.1:8385`.

You can add as many tunnel arguments to ssh as you like.

---

While the above works, you might find that a VPN is a cleaner solution and doesn't require punching holes in your router's natural "firewall". I don't mean the watch-Netflix-in-another-region "VPN" services, but the proper ones, at least some of them are free for home use (I use Tailscale).

Comment: Your command is functioning flawlessly, with some minor cosmetic adjustments. The actual command that worked for me using the native SSH client in Windows 11 is: "ssh user@public_IP -p 3333 -i 'Path to my key' -L8887:127.0.0.1:8888 -R8887:127.0.0.1:8888 -L22001:127.0.0.1:22000 -R22001:127.0.0.1:22000 -N -f." This command successfully establishes port tunnels for both data and GUI purposes. Thank you @ams !

Comment: @HangInThere glad I could help. Sorry about the port number (I'm clearly confused with other tools), I'll fix it right away. Welcome to superuser; please "accept" the answer.